# HOW TO XML mapping in db2?

Tags: xml, db2

I have a xml file save on the pc.

I want direct shredding xml file into relational table
 which utility  can I use, Load and Import can do it?

exists a solution without pureXML?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the [`DECOMPOSE XML DOCUMENT`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0022721.html) command which would require to have an XML schema registered in DB2.

Another option is to first load and store the XML documents in DB2 in a XML column, then use [`XMLTABLE`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0023903.html) to shred the documents into relational format. Only a single table can be produced with that method.

Comment: thank you . I'm also studying these methods, but I'm interested to know if there is a tool /utility of db2 like import and load loading tool that load data  and shredding directly.
by guiida I seem to have understood that these two allow loading in XML type but can not make shredding directly

Comment: and  
and if I do not have a schema  how you do? 
I'm studying all these cases @data_henrik

Answer (score 0):

You could use Navicat. I think that it has functions to import from XML, CSV...

http://www.navicat.com/es/download/navicat-premium

Answer (score 0):

and and if I do not have a schema how you do? I'm studying all these cases